# Gradle build fails for Received status code 407 from server: Proxy Authentication Required, but another project's with similar deps succeeds

Tags: java, spring, gradle, aws-sdk

```
Could not resolve com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:1.11.438.
Required by:
  project : > com.amazonaws:amazon-kinesis-client:1.10.0 > com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-dynamodb:1.11.438
  project : > com.amazonaws:amazon-kinesis-client:1.10.0 > com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-kinesis:1.11.438
  project : > com.amazonaws:amazon-kinesis-client:1.10.0 > com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-cloudwatch:1.11.438
  project : > com.amazonaws:amazon-kinesis-client:1.10.0 > com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-dynamodb:1.11.438 > com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-s3:1.11.438
  project : > com.amazonaws:amazon-kinesis-client:1.10.0 > com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-dynamodb:1.11.438 > com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-s3:1.11.438 > com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-kms:1.11.438
```

> Could not resolve com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:1.11.438.
>   Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-core/1.11.438/aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.438.pom'.
>   Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-core/1.11.438/aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.438.pom'. Received status code 407 from server: Proxy Authentication Required

I get the above errors on `./gradlew clean build` in one java/spring/gradle project, but in another very similar java/spring/gradle project that I have open at the same time which has the same dependencies and then some, the gradle build runs successfully, so it seems something is wrong with the specific project.

I do not have any proxy settings/config in the project that works.

here are the deps in the successful project:

```
dependencies {
//spring
implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter")
implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')

//aws
implementation("com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-sts:${depVersions.awsSdk}")
implementation("com.amazonaws:amazon-kinesis-client:${depVersions.kcl}")
implementation("com.amazonaws:amazon-kinesis-producer:${depVersions.kpl}")
implementation("com.amazonaws:dynamodb-streams-kinesis-adapter:${depVersions.dynamoStreams}")
implementation("redis.clients:jedis:${depVersions.redis}")

//azure
implementation("com.microsoft.azure:applicationinsights-web:${depVersions.appInsights}")
implementation("com.microsoft.azure:applicationinsights-logging-logback:${depVersions.appInsights}")
implementation("com.microsoft.azure:applicationinsights-logging-log4j2:${depVersions.ailog4j}")
implementation("com.microsoft.azure:azure-eventhubs:${depVersions.azureEventHubs}")

//util
implementation("com.google.code.gson:gson:${depVersions.gson}")
implementation("org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j:${depVersions.log4j}")
implementation("com.netflix.feign:feign-slf4j:${depVersions.slf4j}")
implementation("org.json:json:${depVersions.json}")
}
```

and the deps from the project in question that throws the above error:

```
dependencies {
//spring
implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter')
implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')

//aws
implementation("com.amazonaws:amazon-kinesis-client:${depVersions.kcl}")
implementation("com.amazonaws:amazon-kinesis-producer:${depVersions.kpl}")

//azure
implementation("com.microsoft.azure:applicationinsights-web:${depVersions.appInsights}")
implementation("com.microsoft.azure:applicationinsights-logging-logback:${depVersions.appInsights}")
implementation("com.microsoft.azure:applicationinsights-logging-log4j2:${depVersions.ailog4j}")

//util
implementation("com.google.code.gson:gson:${depVersions.gson}")

}
```

also, in the latter (project with error) build.gradle file, the compiler cannot resolve symbols like bootRun{} or bootJar{} and i cant figure out why, their configurations seem equal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out i needed to update the proxy password in my gradle.properties file